# Resizing table to contents in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am a beginner to Qt and PyQt, and would like to resize a table's width so that is shows each column in full.

Here is my current code that just shows a test label and the table in question:

```
tableHeaders = ["Title","Artist","Spotify","YouTube","Local"]

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        label = QLabel("Test")
        table = QTableWidget(4, 5)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tableHeaders)
        for x, track in enumerate(tracks):
            for y, cell in enumerate(track):
                table.setItem(x,y,QTableWidgetItem(cell))
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(label,0,0)
        grid.addWidget(table,0,1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle("TableTest")
        self.show()
```

This creates a table of the default width and height. I know I can resize the table manually by specifying a pixel count, but how do you resize the table so all the columns are shown in full, regardless of their contents? sizeHint just seems to return the default table size.

Comment: I think this was incorrectly marked as a duplicate.   The linked answer addresses resizing columns based on contents.  The question was about resizing REGARDLESS of the contents.

Comment: The duplicate was what I wanted, I'm just bad at explaining things.